# Vue.js Rendering table with multiple tbody

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vue-component

Basically I have five objects in an array, in every object, there is an attribute called `isLastRow` with boolean value. 
I want to have a table with multiple `tbody` tag, when the `item.isLastRow` is true, the next index would create new `tbody` with tr. Obviously, my current attempt just iterates the items and render five `tbody`, the expect result would be just two `tbody`. The first `tbody` will have two `tr` and the last `tbody` has three `tr`.

```
let items = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: a,
        isLastRow: false,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: a,
        isLastRow: true,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: b,
        isLastRow: false,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: b,
        isLastRow: false,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: b,
        isLastRow: true,
    },
]



<template v-for="item in items">
  <tbody :key="item.id">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ item.text }}
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

This is the result I expect to be

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use a computed property to format your data structure to be something like

```js
[
  [
    { id: 0, text: a, isLastRow: false },
    { id: 1, text: a, isLastRow: true },
  ],
  [
    { id: 2, text: b, isLastRow: false },
    { id: 3, text: b, isLastRow: false },
    { id: 4, text: b, isLastRow: true },
  ],
];
```

e.g.,

```js
computed: {
  getFormatedItems() {
    const sections = [[]];
    let index = 0;

    this.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.lastRow) {
         index++;
         section[index] = [];
      }
      section[index].push(item);
    });
  },
},
```

Then you can write you template like

```html
<template v-for="(section, index) in getFormatedItems">
  <tbody :key="index">
    <tr v-for="item in section" :key="item.id">
      <td>{{item.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Comment: This give me an error on eslint. Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive

Comment: However, the point of having a nested array is good. I will try to fix that eslint error

Comment: Found it, the v-for="item in section" should be in the tr. Not the tbody. Anyways thank for your help